# Python to call shell script with arguments

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script I need to call from a Python script.  Only thing is that is needs to pass 7 parameters, that are basically variables, and some of those contain spaces.

I see a lot of references to os.system, and to subprocess, but what about the parameters with spaces?   I think those will cause an issue.

Comment: You can use [`f strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (python 3.6+) to format strings and add those parameters

Comment: do you have an example that you have tried?

Comment: Put quotes around the arguments that contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2:

```
subject = "Proposal"
to = "LandonStatis@stackoverflow.com"
from = "Joshua@stackoverflow.com"
REPORT_DIRECTORY = "/home/reports"
file = "/home/files/proposal.txt"
message = "Please accept me as the best answer"

#i didnt include the "flag" because i dont know the flag format

os.system('./home/scripts/send_email.pl "'+subject+'" "'+to+'" "'+from+'" "'+REPORT_DIRECTORY+'" "'+file+'" "'+message+'"')
```

---

Edit:

If you want to add a variable, you can do so like this

```
os.system('ls -al '+str(x))
```

---

For example, if your username is "landon statis" with a space,

you can do this: `os.system('ls -al "/home/landon statis/Desktop"')`

(notice the space in the command above?)

This works for both Windows and Linux.

> Use double quotes to prevent word splitting. An argument enclosed in
> double quotes presents itself as a single word, even if it contains
> whitespace separators.

This is the source, which is a link to Linux Documentation Project. Check them out, it's very useful: [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide: Chapter 5 - Quoting](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: If the value is actually in a variable, so:  x = "/home/landon /var/www".    I'm a tad new at this, so if I enclose it in quotes:   os.system('ls -al "x"')   Will Python be able to resolve that?

Comment: @LandonStatis if it is a variable, do `os.system('ls -al '+str(x))`

Comment: appreciate the help.   I set a bunch of variables and tried your suggestion, and it did not work as expected.   I'll paste it here.   Sorry for everything being on one line, but I've never figured how to format within the comments here.

Comment: So, here are the variables:    subject = "Test is a test"      rec = "me@mail.com"      to = "me@mail.com"      message = "This is the body"     file = "None"      flag = "N"      dir = "/tmp".        Ok, then here is the calling line I use.   Note that I figured just make spaces between the parameters:      os.system('/home/scripts/send_email.pl ' + str(subject) + ' ' + str(to) + ' ' + str(rec) + ' ' + str(dir) + ' ' + str(file) + ' ' + str(message) + ' ' + str(flag)).       The message I got back was:    $ ./check.py   -   test/me@mail.com: not readable

Comment: @LandonStatis could you write the FULL code in shell form? I will convert it to python form.

Comment: @Josuha, it's a one line call from shell, which actually calls a Perl script like this:      ./home/scripts/send_email.pl "$subject" "$to" "$from" "$REPORT_DIRECTORY" $file "$message" "$flag"

Comment: Is working.   Appreciate your time and efforts.   Was a few confusing things regarding the quotes and how Python would interpret them.   Many thanks for this.......

Comment: @LandonStatis You're welcome :) Mark mine as best answer? :D

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `os.system` or `subprocess` with `shell=True`. Both execute a shell and are potentially vulnerable to shell injections. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations for more details.

Best way is to use `subprocess` and hand it a list of arguments. Example: Let's just use a Shell script that print its arguments. `myscript`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for arg in "$@"; do
   echo "argument: $arg"
done
```

Then you can call this script using a list as argument:

```py
subprocess.run(["./myscript", "first", "argument with space", "third"])
```

Output:

```
argument: first
argument: argument with space
argument: third
```